# Does an impurity spread if it comes in contact with running water

Tags: hadith, sharia, sunni, wudu, taharah

Some urine got on a bathroom carpet and so i put it in a bucket in the bathtub. Then when i went to wash myself, the bucket fell over and thus the side of the carpet that had urine on it touched a side of the bathtub as well as the floor of the bathtub in the back. I had the water on during this time. My question is: Does the running water that comes in contact with the carpet with urine make all the running water impure, like the water in the front of the tub/next to the drain (as all the water is connected?)

I ask because I'm scared that if there is urine then it got everywhere in the house (because my hands were wet and i touched many things around the house), and still stayed inside the bathtub, and so when my family made wudu, the impurity got onto them.